# node.js - JavaScript Node: cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, express-jwt

am using MERN stack in my project and am logging in And when I log in, I can do that normally until I'm on the home page, then I get an error (Not valid), although I see the username and I can access all pages, but I can't view posts or create any post
This is the code that displays the error

```
export const getPost = (token) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({type: POST_TYPES.LOADING_POST, payload: true})
    const res = await getDataApi('posts', token)
    dispatch({type: POST_TYPES.GET_POST, payload: res.data})
    dispatch({type: POST_TYPES.LOADING_POST, payload: false})
    console.log(res) 
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.msg) // this line gave me "not valid" then after second gave me "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'following')"
    console.log(token)// gave me undefined , after second it printing the token
    dispatch({
        type: 'ALERT',
        payload: {
            error: err.response.data.msg
        }
    })
}}
```

this is auth token code

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const token = req.header("Authorization")

    if(!token) return res.status(500).json({msg: "Not Valid!"})

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESSTOKENSECRET)
    if(!decoded) return res.status(500).json({msg: "Not Valid!"})

    const user = await User.findOne({_id: decoded.id})
    req.user = user;
    next();
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
}
```

even the token is printed normaly,
I don't know what's wrong,
would appreciate any help

Comment: Which line throws this error? Can you show the full error stack?